# How to check the content of 2 or more values that can be contained in the resulting stream of elements - Flux<T> (spring WebFlux)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a method that validates containing some elements in **Stream**.

- Task

For example, there is a **sequence** that has a series of numbers (the numbers are not repeated), and each number is larger than the other :

**1, 20, 35, 39, 45, 43**

... It is necessary to check whether there is a specified range in this **stream**, for example **35 ...49**. If there is no such **range**, then you need to throw an **Exception**.

But since this is **asynchronous processing**, the usual methods do not work here. After all, we process elements in the stream and do not know what the next element will be.

The elements of this sequence need to be folded, the addition should be done gradually (as soon as the initial range of elements is found).

During the service, you need to check whether there is an **endpoint** in the **generated sequence** and when the entire flow of elements is received, but this point is not, then ask for an **Exception**, since the **upper limit** of the specified **range** is not received

Also, **do not start** calculations until **the starting point** of the specified range is found,

while **we cannot block** *the stream*, otherwise we will get the same Ex**strong text**ception.

How can such a check be organized ?

When I work with a regular thread, it looks like this:

```java
   private boolean isRangeValues() {

        List<BigInteger> sequence = Arrays
                .asList(
                        new BigInteger("11"),
                        new BigInteger("15"),
                        new BigInteger("23"),
                        new BigInteger("27"),
                        new BigInteger("30"));

           BigInteger startRange =   new BigInteger("15");
           BigInteger finishRange = new BigInteger("27");

        boolean isStartRangeMember = sequence.contains(startRange);
        boolean isFinishRangeMembe = sequence.contains(finishRange);


        return isStartRangeMember && isFinishRangeMember;
    }
```

But I have a task to process a stream of elements that are generated at some interval.
To get the result, a reactive stack is used in **Spring** and I get the result in **Flux**.

Just convert to a list and process, - it will not work, there will be an **Exception**.
After filtering these elements, the stream will continue to be processed.

But if I see an error in data validation at the time of **filtering** (in this case, there are no elements that are needed), then I will need to request an **Exception**, which will be processed **globally** and returned to the client.

```java
    @GetMapping("v1/sequence/{startRange}/{endRange}")
    Mono<BigInteger> getSumSequence(
            @PathVariable BigInteger startRange,
            @PathVariable BigInteger endRange) {

        Flux<BigInteger> sequenceFlux = sequenceGenerated();
        
         validateSequence(sequenceFlux)
      
       return sum(sequenceFlux );
     }

     private Mono<BigInteger> sum (Flux<BigInteger> sequenceFlux ){
      .....
     }

       private void validateSequence(Flux<BigInteger> sequenceFlux){
         ... is wrong
         throw new RuntimeException();
     }
}
```

I came up with some solution (I published it in this topic).

```java
    public void validateRangeSequence(sequenceDto dto) {

        Flux<BigInteger> sequenceFlux = dto.getSequenceFlux();
        BigInteger startRange = dto.getStartRange();
        BigInteger endRange = dto.getEndRange();

        Mono<Boolean> isStartRangeMember = sequenceFlux.hasElement(startRange);
        
        Mono<Boolean> isEndRangeMember = sequenceFlux.hasElement(endRange);

        if ( !isStartRangeMember.equals(isEndRangeMember) ){
            throw new RuntimeException("error");
        }
```

But it doesn't work as expected, even the correct results cause an exception.

**Update**

```java
public void validateRangeSeq(RangeSequenceDto dto) {

        Flux<BigInteger> sequenceFlux = dto.getSequenceFlux();
        BigInteger startRange = dto.getStartRange();
        BigInteger endRange = dto.getEndRange();

        Mono<Boolean> isStartRangeMember = sequenceFlux.hasElement(startRange);
        Mono<Boolean> isEndRangeMember = sequenceFlux.hasElement(endRange);

        sequenceFlux
                .handle((number, sink) -> {
                    if (!isStartRangeMember.equals(isEndRangeMember) ){
                        sink.error(new RangeWrongSequenceExc("It is wrong given range!."));
                    } else {
                        sink.next(number);
                    }
                });
    }
```

- Unfortunately , That decision also doesn't work.

```java
        sequenceFlux
                .handle(((bigInteger, synchronousSink) -> {
                    if(!bigInteger.equals(startRange)){
                        synchronousSink.error(new RuntimeException("!!!!!!!!!!! ---- Wrong range!"));
                    } else {
                        synchronousSink.next(bigInteger);
                    }
                }));
```

It piece of code - It doesn't work. (does not react in any way)

Who thinks what about this ? Should this be done or are there other approaches ?

I am not familiar with **Reactive stack** in Spring and do not know how to handle such a situation here.

Maybe someone has ideas on how to organize such **filtering** and **do not block** the processing of elements in the **stream**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like that

```
    Flux<Integer> yourStream = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).share();
Flux.zip(
        yourStream.filter(integer -> integer.equals(4)),
        yourStream.filter(integer -> integer.equals(6)),
        (integer, integer2) -> Tuple2.of(integer, integer2))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: thank you. But I wrote above that although I use the filter, it is important to me that after filtering, if at least one value from the specified range is not in the processed stream of elements, I should throw Excpetion, then do not add, if values from the desired range are found in the stream of elements, only then start counting these values.  2 filters can skip for example - one value, the same Exception should be thrown, if not one, Exception should also be thrown

Comment: After all, the elements in the Stream are processed one by one. For example, there is 2, 4, 7, 9, 11. The range is set : 4 .... 10. The filter starts skipping elements after 4, and the addition of incoming elements begins, but suddenly the filter did not find the upper limit in the processed stream of elements, at this moment (that is, at the end of processing) it should throw Exception . Or perform calculations only after all elements from the specified range are filtered out, but also if the lower element of the specified range is not found. you also need to throw Exception.

Comment: i dont understand very will what do you want to achive but if there is no mach zip will not emit any item so in switchIfEmpty you can throw an error. if you find  one in the stream you can do  .take(1) and it will not emit items anymore if 1 is found